# Link to new tab in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried to open a component in new tab using Link in React router, it opens a 404 not found instead of react component,

React entry point js,

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Route,Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/Home" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('reactDiv'));
```

Home Component,

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h2> Home Page </h2>
            <Link to={`/about`} target="_blank"> 
                About
            </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### About Component

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h2> About Page </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I expected the About component to display in new tab, but it opens a new tab with 404 page not found error.

Could any one let me know how to open a component in new tab.

Comment: you have to setup `historyApiFallback' to true

Comment: i didnt use webpack dev server, so how to set this historyApiFallback option??

Comment: make sure, on server (any), when no route matches on server, you serve  your html file that contains react's generated .js file.

Comment: You need to use this.props.children in Home component.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect Webpack isn't 'empowered' to handle all routes request on your current server.

If you are using `express`, then in your `server.js`, make sure you have your routes defined as:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, 'path/to/index.html'));
});
```

The `*` wildcard tells express to render your `index.html` on every route request.

Another edit I'd suggest is that you remove the preceeding slashes from your route definitions. Try making it:

I tried to open a component in new tab using Link in React router, it opens a 404 not found instead of react component,

```
  <Route path="Home" component={Home}></Route>
  <Route path="about" component={About}></Route>
```

I've had some issues with absolutely definiting paths with `react-router` in the past.

Comment: As you said i am using express in server.js, and routes is defined with '*', but even then its not working,                           app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(8081);

Comment: Could you try removing the preceeding slashes from the routes definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Your router should be something like :

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
         <Route path="about" component={About} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Then your app should be something like :

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {this.props.children}
        );
    }
}


export default App;
```

That should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

Your link should be `<Link to="about">About </Link>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it didn't helped me, still i have same issue, i am using maven for running the project, will it cause any issue?

Comment: You should also change your Link. I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried as you said, when i run the frontend using express Link To works perfectly, when i try to run with mvn spring boot, it doesnt works.